# Calculate "branch distance" metric in Python

Tags: python, testing, metrics

I want to calculate the "branch distance" of a Python program for a given line. This metric

> indicates how "far" a branch is from being executed. For example, if a
> conditional "if (a == b)" is to be executed as true, the "raw"
> distance can be computed as "|a − b|". In this way, the closer the
> values of a and b are to one another, the lower the branch distance.

- ([Shamshiri](https://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/127562/), 2018)

I am trying to implement this metric in Python, and I already use [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) to analyze which lines are executed. Still, it does not include the variable assignment history.

Does anyone have an idea of how to accomplish this?

Comment: I doubt that there will be a standard way to accomplish this, since predicates are arbitrarily complex. You may need to hard-code different common cases?

Comment: The main problem is that I cannot capture the local variables just before the predicates are evaluated. I worked around the problem by manually inserting `print(<line number>, json.dumps(locals()))` before every branching statement. But of course, I'd rather like to do this automatically somehow. I tried injecting namespaces, but this did not work. There is also [pycrunch-trace], but it is not open source as far as I know.